# WebClient returning unidentified encoding from Google Translate API?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, webclient, google-translation-api

I'm using this link: https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=en&dt=t&q=myTextHere

When I feed it Japanese characters such as, テスト中..., the DownloadString method returns strange characters such as this: ãƒ † ã,¹ãƒä¸ ...

The correct string should be "Under Test..."

You can see for yourself by clicking the link on your browser: [https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=en&dt=t&q=テスト中](https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=en&dt=t&q=%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E4%B8%AD)

I've tried multiple things such as setting the client's encoding to UTF-8 and using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myText)` but I could not get what my browser returns. Swapping DownloadString for DownloadFile as txt returns the same incorrect text. How do I get the same results as the browser?

Here's a small code snippet that resembles my environment:

```
String s = "テスト中";
Console.WriteLine("src="+s);
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string downloadString = @client.DownloadString("https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=en&dt=t&q=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s));
Console.WriteLine("data:{\n"+downloadString+"\n}");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't the faintest idea why Google Translate API returns garbled characters. The malformed WebClient response includes "fr" instead of "ja", suggesting that the API misinterprets your text as French (!) instead of Japanese. Or something.

In any case, after some experimentation I found that the API behaves properly if you set the User-Agent header:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)");
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string downloadString = client.DownloadString("https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=en&dt=t&q=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s));
// Result: [[["Under test","テスト中",null,null,3]],null,"ja",...]
```

Comment: Strange but that works beautifully. When I said "same results as my browser," I completely overlooked the possibility of setting the `User-Agent` header. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the interesting question.